# Google cloud compute engine with Startup script

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a Cloud function to spin up a VM with startup script. This startup python script uses Storage, BQ API's etc. For application authentication, besides setting the "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" in the VM environment how can I have this working? I have tried running "gcloud beta auth application-default login" as part of VM start up before executing the startup script but no luck in executing the startup script.
Please advise.

Comment: you can review [this document](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python) to authenticate via environment variable. like export `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"`

Comment: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS would require to copy the SA account key file onto the VM...I found the awnser...you can use compute engine credentials for accessing the client libraries without having to rely on key file. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production